# How does Sobolev norm change with respect to domain size?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $u\in H^s(0,r)$, let's say $s\ge 0$. It then follows that $u|_{(0,r')}\in H^s(0,r')$ for any $r'<r$.  But is it true that $|u|_{H^s(0,r)}\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow 0$?  How about negative s, too?

Comment: Can you provide the definition for H^s on a bounded domain when a is not an integer, of course it is not the Fourier one

Comment: It can be considered as restrictions of elements of $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ to $(0,r)$ with the norm as the infimum of norms of all extensions. Another way to define is to use interpolation between integer indexed spaces. A third way is to use the integral definition of fractional Sobolev norm on domains.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is true using Lebesgue dominated convergence for $s \geq 0$. For exemple for $s=1$ you write, for $r' < r$ :

$$\int_{B_{r'}} |u|^2 \ \mathrm{d}x + \int_{B_{r'}} |\nabla u|^2 \ \mathrm{d}x = \int_{B_{r}} \mathcal{1}_{B_{r'}}|u|^2 \ \mathrm{d}x + \int_{B_{r}} \mathcal{1}_{B_{r'}}|\nabla u|^2 \ \mathrm{d}x $$
and you use Lebesgue dominated convergence when $r' \rightarrow 0$ on each integrals.

Comment: Thanks. You meant $s=1$ I suppose. How about $s<0$?

Comment: Yes you're right. For $s<0$ it's a more subtle question. I guess you could use a formula like $$||u||_{H^{-1}(B_r)}= \sup_{\varphi \in H^1_0(B_r) \atop ||\nabla \varphi||_{L^2(B_r)}=1 } |u(\varphi)|$$ but it's more complicated to make $r \rightarrow 0$. My guess is it should make $0$ also.